# Making an application Database Agnostic

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have an existing C# application, which I intend to make Database Agnostic, in such a way that the Database Engine is abstracted from the Business Logic completely.

Here is my approach to make one -

```
public abstract class DbEngine // I can also make it an Interface
{       
}

public class SQLDBEngine : DbEngine
{
    public bool ExecuteSP(string SPName)
    {           
    }

    public void ExecuteInlineQuery(String SQLQuery)
    {
    }
}

public class MySQLDBEngine : DbEngine
{
    public bool ExecuteSP(string SPName)
    {
    }

    public void ExecuteInlineQuery(String SQLQuery)
    {
    }
}
```

I then have a Factory class, which takes care of Instantiating the appropriate DbEngine object -

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    string CurrentEngine;

    public ConnectionManager()
    {
        // Read from configuration file to know which database to configure
        // Config returns wither MS or MY
        // MS = SQLDBEngine
        // MY = MYSQLDBEngine       
    }

    public DbEngine GetDBInstance()
    {
        switch(CurrentEngine)
        {
            case "MS":
                                return new SQLDBEngine();

            case "MY":
                                return new MySQLDBEngine();

            default:
                                return new SQLDBEngine();               
        }
    }
}
```

The Business Logic will only interact with the ConnectionManager object, thus abstracting the Database completely from it .

The Client will interact with the following  code-

```
ConnectionManager conn  = new ConnectionManager();
DBEngine obj = conn.GetDBInstance();

obj.ExecuteInlineQuery("select * from tblItems");
```

The Problem here, is that if the we introduce MongoDBEngine as the new database engine, this will require once more class MongoDBEngine - but since it doesn't have a Stored Procedure like feature, so ExecuteSP doesn't make sense and hence the Business Logic call will fail.

Iam just trying to encapsulate the Database Engine from the Business Logic, so that when the database is changed, the Business Logic should not undergo any change.

Is there any design pattern or technique that I could follow ?

Comment: Microsoft's Entity Framework is an attempt at doing just that: it provides an abstracted (LINQ based) interface to whatever database is connected, and it masks missing functionality in its implementation-specific connectors. So it can translate queries to tsql and pl/SQL for example. Good luck if you are going to implement that yourself, I once did it for mssql, pl/SQL, mysql and access and it was a huge pain to limit myself to a common subset of the four database systems' capabilities. anyhow, abstracting and then using a `ExecuteInlineQuery` is pointless IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to expose the functionality of the database to the application, you should abstract away the method of access. Instead of providing an ability to execute a query, embed that query or stored procedure call or insert/update/delete command as part of your repository class.

```
public class MySQLCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MySQLCustomerRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<CustomerOrder> GetCustomerOrdersByDate(int customerId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        //open a MySQL connection and execute query to retrieve customer orders
    }
}

public class MongoCustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MongoCustomerRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<CustomerOrder> GetCustomerOrdersByDate(int customerId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        //connect to mongo, get customers by running query
    }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    List<CustomerOrder> GetCustomerOrdersByDate(int customerId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
}
```

The consuming application itself should have no knowledge of queries, because the repository itself takes care of those details.

Part of the point of this is that each database will have different queries and commands that make sense for it. An SQL query written for MS SQL may not be the same as one written for Oracle, and of course SQL won't work at all on a no-SQL database. So each implementation should be responsible for using the correct interactions for its corresponding database, and your consuming application shouldn't need to know how that works, because it should always access the database via an interface, never through a concrete implementation .

Comment: I like this answer and find it useful. Especially as it focuses on leaking implementation concerns. A lot of these types of answers jump straight to the abstraction behind an interface, but the abstraction basically leaks everything about the implementation and is just a leaky interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last answer from mason is a really step forward through a good desing. I would go one step further in OO desing and try to think as an object page for a Dto and return a sequence of something. A change i would do is to encapsulate the parameters of the methods inside the object and inject them through constructor, so this way you will have multiple clases implementing an abstraction of your query(1 class for a paged sequence, other class for searching for id, start and end time, etc. The result will be the same return type) instead of a big monster with a bunch of methods returning the same type. This way you get better mantainability, so if you have a issue with a mongo class for a specific query, you check one tiny class and not a GOD class, here is some paging desing:

```
/// <summary>
/// DTO
/// </summary>
public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Define a contract that get a sequence of something
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public interface IFetch<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Fetch();
}

/// <summary>
/// Define a pageTemplate
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public abstract class PageTemplate<T> : IFetch<T>
{
    protected readonly int pageSize;
    protected readonly int page;

    public PageTemplate(int page, int pageSize)
    {
        this.page = page;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> Fetch();
}

/// <summary>
/// Design a MyDto Page object, Here you are using the Template method
/// </summary>
public abstract class MyDtoPageTemplate : PageTemplate<CustomerOrder>
{
    public MyDtoPageTemplate(int page, int pageSize) : base(page, pageSize) { }
}

/// <summary>
/// You can use ado.net for full performance or create a derivated class of MyDtoPageTemplate to use Dapper
/// </summary>
public sealed class SqlPage : MyDtoPageTemplate
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public SqlPage(int page, int pageSize, string connectionString) : base(page, pageSize)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> Fetch()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            //This can be injected from contructor or encapsulated here, use a Stored procedure, is fine
            string commandText = "Select Something";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows) yield break;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return new CustomerOrder()
                        {
                            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            Name = reader.GetString(1),
                            Value = reader.GetString(2)
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public sealed class MongoDbPage : MyDtoPageTemplate
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public MongoDbPage(int page, int pageSize, string connectionString) : base(page, pageSize)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> Fetch()
    {
        //Return From CustomerOrder from mongoDb
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// You can test and mock the fetcher
/// </summary>
public sealed class TestPage : IFetch<CustomerOrder>
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> Fetch()
    {
        yield return new CustomerOrder() { Id = 0, Name = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty };
        yield return new CustomerOrder() { Id = 1, Name = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty };
    }
}

public class AppCode
{
    private readonly IFetch<CustomerOrder> fetcher;
    /// <summary>
    /// From IoC, inject a fetcher object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fetcher"></param>
    public AppCode(IFetch<CustomerOrder> fetcher)
    {
        this.fetcher = fetcher;
    }
    public IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> FetchDtos()
    {
        return fetcher.Fetch();
    }
}

public class CustomController
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public void RunSql()
    {
        var fetcher = new SqlPage(1, 10, connectionString);
        var appCode = new AppCode(fetcher);
        var dtos = appCode.FetchDtos();
    }

    public void RunTest()
    {
        var fetcher = new TestPage();
        var appCode = new AppCode(fetcher);
        var dtos = appCode.FetchDtos();
    }
}
```